# Appending with 2> and with >>

Tags: bash, shell

Why do some scripts use `2>` instead of `>>`?
Is the 2 just a multiplier of the `>`'s ?

Comment: [Read the Bash manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html)

Answer (score 1):

1>> and 2>> are redirections for specific file-descriptors, in this case the standard output (file descriptor 1) and standard error (file descriptor 2).
**2>**  Will output the error in the script to a file. 
**">>"**  Will append the output of a command to an existing file. If file doesn`t exists then it will create the file add the output to the file.

See this link =>  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183125/what-does-1-and-2-mean-in-a-bash-script

Answer (score 0):

For `2>` means you are re-directing standard errors to a file or etc.

`>>` means we are trying to do concatenating operation.

Examples:

Without `2>` :

```
ls -ld singh_test
ls: cannot access singh_test: No such file or directory
```

With `2>`:

```
ls -ld singh_test 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Can I also append the standard errors with `2>>`?

Comment: Yes, you can append using >>.

Comment: @thraizz, no need fr single command if you are creating a new file then it will write in single file only by appending it by `2>` itself but if file is already created one then then you could use `2>>`

Answer (score 0):

I/O redirection in bash is not pretty, but is very flexible.

I/O operates as "streams". The standard input stream is 0. Standard output is 1. Error output is 2.

`echo foo` send the literal string "foo" to the commands *standard output* stream 1. You can redirect this like so: `echo foo 1>x` which will send the data on stream 1 to a file named x. For output redirections of this sort, standard output is the default, so you will usually see people leave the 1 off, like this: `echo foo >x`

This means you can specify the redirections of the standard output and error output of a command separately.

```
ls -ld . bogus >ok 2>err
```

This directs the successful listing into `ok` and the error message about `bogus` not existing into `err`.

By default, `>` creates a file if one does not exist, but silently truncates one that already does. `>>` will also create a file if it does not exist, but will append to existing data rather than truncating . Thus,

```
ls -ld . bogus >ok 2>>err
```

Will create either or both, but any previous content in `ok` will be lost, while `err` will add a new line on the end of the file.

If you don't want that behavior, then `set -o noclobber` will change it so that `>` will create a new file, but will fail if the file already exists. You can explicitly tell it to truncate any existing file under `noclobber` with `>|` for cases where you still want that.

You can also close streams with (for example) `2>&-` and create new duplicates with `1>&3`.

See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) for a more complete reference.